# lookuperror unknown encoding cp720 in django when running on diffrent computer

Tags: python, django

I have a django site that when I run it on my computer,every thing is good,but when I run it on another computer,I can't login with my username and password and that sounds like the user is not in my database while the user is in user auth table in sqlite.
then I go to shell to create another user,but it doesn't let me create a new user and have this error:
lookuperror unknown encoding cp720
what should I do about it?

**Solution:**

```
chcp 1250
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find out why the other machine doesn't have [the full set of codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) installed, and rectify that.